# Can you help me understand this math problem?

Tags: probability

A bag contains five yellow balls and four blue balls. Your goal is to draw two blue balls.

You draw two balls at random. Once you have drawn two balls, you put back any yellow balls and redraw so that you again have two drawn balls. What is the probability that you now have two blue balls?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: You say you want help understanding the problem. What exactly do you find unclear in this description?

Comment: So, I know that the probability that both balls are blue is 1/6, but I don't know what to do from here.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please try to use more descriptive titles.  Every question on this site could probably be titled, "Please help me to understand this math problem."

Comment: Break it into cases.  You might draw two blue balls the first time, or a blue and a yellow, or two blues.  What is the probability of each case?  What is the probability of success in each case?

Comment: Are you looking for have _exactly_ two blue balls or _at least_ two? If got at least one blue on the first draw, you could end up with more than two after the second. Do you stop if you get two blues right off the bat? The way you’ve described this process, you always draw twice. All of these details affect the calculation.

Comment: **Please do not discuss this problem! This is an active homework problem.** @As1an Mushro0m: I realize that homework may be challenging. If you wish to receive some help from the staff or other students, I encourage you to use the resources that the online classes provide, such as the Message Board. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if you mean this or the extended version which has infinite sample points
[image: see]

Comment: Guessing that this answers the question.  I wrote "guessing" because some (most) of it is unreadable.  Nice analysis, though!

Comment: :) Sorry for illegible handwriting, @mjw

Comment: No need to apologize to me.  There is probably a way to make a nice diagram with $\LaTeX$ or **MathJax**.  Don't know if you want to go through the trouble ...

Answer (score 0):

I would split the problem up into three cases:

- Case $1$: You pick $2$ blue balls on the first draw
- Case $2$: You pick $1$ blue and $1$ yellow on the first draw, *and* then you redraw a blue
- Case 3: You pick $2$ yellow balls on the first draw, *and* then you redraw $2$ blue balls

Let's consider case $1$:

$$P(2 \text{ blues}) = \frac{4}{9} \times \frac{3}{8} = \frac{12}{72}= \frac{1}{6}$$

So there is  a $1/6$ chance that you pick $2$ blues straight away and do not need to redraw. However, you also need to think about cases 2 and 3, where you still might end up with $2$ blues after you redraw. Case 2:

$$
P(1 \text{ blue and } 1 \text{ yellow}) = \left(\frac{4}{9} \times \frac{5}{8}\right) +\left(\frac{5}{9} \times \frac{4}{8}\right) = \frac{5}{9}
$$

Notice how case 2 accounts for one when you pick a blue, then a yellow; *and* when you pick a yellow, then a blue. Now you have to consider the chance of getting a blue when you redraw:

$$
P(\text{Drawing a blue, given that you have drawn $1$ blue and $1$ yellow}) = \frac{3}{8}
$$

(If I understand correctly here, you took $2$ balls out, and then put the yellow that you didn't want back in.)

Therefore, the total probability for this case is:

$$
\frac{5}{9} \times \frac{3}{8} = \frac{15}{72} = \frac{5}{24}
$$

Can you figure it out from here?

Answer (score 0):

There several things that can happen:

1) You can draw two blue balls on you first try and are done.

2) You can draw one blue ball and one yellow ball on your first try and you replace the yellow and draw a second blue ball and you are done.

3) You can draw one blue ball and one yellow ball on your first try and you replace the yellow and draw a yellow ball and you have failed.

4) You can draw two yellow  balls and you replace them both with blue balls and you are done.

5) You can draw tow yellow balls and replace them both but fail to draw two balls.

1), 2) and 4) are successful and 3) and 5) are failures.

The 5) choices are mutually exclusive (one or another can happen but two or more can not both happen) and exhaustive (I've covered all possibilities).

Being mutually exclusive means: $P(\text{success})=P(1\text{ or }2\text{ or } 4) = P(1) + P(2) + P(4)$.  And being exhaustive means $P(1) + P(2) + P(3) + P(4) + P(5) = 1$.

So what is $P(1), P(2), P(4)$?  And what is $P(\text{success})=P(1\text{ or }2\text{ or } 4) = P(1) + P(2) + P(4)$?

1) The probability of the first ball being blue is $\frac 49$.  ANd given that occured there are now $3$ blue balls and $5$ yellow balls remaining.  The probability of the second being blue is $\frac 38$ and so the probability of both is $\frac 49\frac 38=\frac 16$.  So $P(1) = \frac 16$.

2) I guess we should break this into cases.  The probability of the first ball being blue is $\frac 49$ and the probability of the second being yellow is $\frac 58$.  So the probability of blue than yellow is $\frac 49\frac 58=\frac {5}{18}$.

And the probability of the first being yellow and the second blue is $\frac 59\frac 48=\frac {5}{18}$.  So the probability of one beig yellow and the other blue regardless of order is $\frac 5{18} + \frac 5{18} = \frac 59$.

Now we put the yellow back and there are $3$ blue balls, and $5$ yellow balls.  So the probability of *now* drawing a blue ball is $\frac 38$.

So $P(2) = \frac 59\frac 38=\frac 5{24}$.

4) The probability of the first ball being yellow is $\frac 59$ and that leaves $4$ yellow and $4$ blue.  Then probability the second ball is yellow is $\frac 48$ and the probability that both are yellow is $\frac 59\frac 48= \frac 5{18}$.

We put them back.  And we have 9 balls, ... this is exactly as we started.  And the probability of now pulling two blues is $\frac 16$ as we figured when we figured 1).  So the probability of first drawing two yellows and then two blues is $\frac 5{18}\frac 16 = \frac 5{108}$.

....

And $P= P(1,2,4) = P(1) + P(2) + P(4) = \frac 16 + \frac 5{18}+\frac 5{108}= \frac {1*18 + 5*6 + 5}{108}=\frac {53}{108}$.

Answer (score 0):

What you're having here is a multilevel random experiment (not sure if that's the exact English term).

We're having two random experiments in this case, with the second being dependent on the first. Let's formalize the experiments first:

Let $\mathcal H_{n,b,y} $ be the hypergeometric distribution, with $n$ being the number of draws, $b$ the blue ball count and $y$ the yellow ball count.
 Then $\mathcal H_{n,b,y}(\{k\}) $ tells you the probability to draw exactly $k$ blue balls.

Then the first random experiment has the probability space $(\{0,1,2\},P(\{0,1,2\}),\mathcal H_{2,4,5})$.

The second random experiment can only be given dependent on the outcome of the first. So let $k$ be the number of blue balls we got in the first experiment. 
Then the probability space of the second random experiment is: 
$(\{0,1,2\},P(\{0,1,2\}),\mathcal H_{2-k,4-k,5})$

Our multilevel random experiment therefore has the probability space $(\{0,1,2\}^2,P(\{0,1,2\}^2),\mathbb P )$,
of which we don't know yet its probability distribution $\mathbb P$.

However, we know how it has to look for the first experiment, and the second experiment given the outcome of the first experiment.
We therefore define the random variables $X_1,X_2$ which map to the first and the second random experiment (in this case that means that $X_1$ maps an 
$x\in\{0,1,2\}^2 $ 
onto its first coordinate, and $X_2$ maps onto the second coordinate).

We therefore know:
$$
\mathbb P(X_1 = k) = \mathcal H_{2,4,5}\\
\mathbb P(X_2 = j| X_1 = k) = \mathcal H_{2-j,4-j,5}
$$

Using the law of total probability, we now could calculate $\mathbb P$.

Then we'd only have to define the event "To draw exactly two blue balls", let's call it $A$, which is $A:=\{(0,2),(1,1),(0,2)\} $, and calculate $\mathbb P(A)$.

Since we don't really care about the formula of $\mathbb P$ however, we can also just calculate it for our special case:

For this, we define another random variable $X_3 := X_2+X_1$. In other words, $X_3$ tells us how many blue balls we have drawn in total.

Then we're looking for $\mathbb P(X_3 = 2)$. We therefore have:

$$\begin{align}
&\mathbb P(X_3=2) \\
&=\mathbb P(X_1+X_2 = 2)  \\
&=\mathbb P(X_1 = 2, X_2 =0) + \mathbb P(X_1 = 1, X_2=1) + \mathbb P(X_2 =0, X_1 = 2)  \\
 &= \mathbb P(X_1=2)\mathbb P( X_2 =0| X_1 = 2)
+ \mathbb P(X_1=1)\mathbb P( X_2 =1| X_1 = 1)
+ \mathbb P(X_1=0)\mathbb P( X_2 =2| X_1 = 0)\\
&= \mathcal{H}_{2,4,5}(\{2\})\mathcal{H}_{0,2,5} (\{0\})+ \mathcal{H}_{2,4,5}(\{1\})\mathcal{H}_{1,3,5}(\{1\}) + \mathcal{H}_{2,4,5}(\{0\})\mathcal{H}_{2,4,5}(\{2\})\\
&= 91/216 \approx 0.42
\end{align}$$